# UITableView HeaderView margin when removing separator's left space

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I've removed the separator left margin from my tableview using in the **viewDidLoad**:

```
self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

In my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

The problem is that the header and footer views has been moved too and I want to keep it aligned with the cells' content.

[image]

I've tried to change the frame in the **willDisplayHeaderView** and **willDisplayFooterView** without success. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As *Memon Irshad* suggest, I've created a new label but rather than do it inside the **viewForHeaderInSection** I've do it in **willDisplayHeaderView** because while using this method we can know the size of the headerView.

Then I hide the original textLabel of the TableViewHeader and adding the new framed label. What do you think? Any improvements?

Looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
    let originView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView

    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15,originView.frame.height-30,originView.frame.size.width,20))

    // Setting up the new label
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.font  = Constants.Fonts.HeaderRow
    lbl.textColor = Constants.Colors.TextColored

    // Copying the original text content
    lbl.text = originView.textLabel?.text

    // Hidding the original label
    originView.textLabel?.hidden = true

    originView.addSubview(lbl)
}
```

Comment: `originView.textLabel?.hidden = true` was very important, otherwise the labels would just overlap each other and look weird.

Comment: adding a label here is a bad idea, bc the delegate method gets called multiple times and each time you're adding a new label above already existing one when the view is reused.

Answer (score 1):

Header/Footer cannot stick to your cell's content. I too wasted a lot of time on that

You must add a row to your section and use it as if it is a header/footer

Comment: Thanks. Then Can I preserve the design? (Header without separator lines)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what separator lines are you talking about?

Comment: You can customize that particular row(the one you want to use as header) as much as you want, you can change its height/you can change color, borderwidth everything. It can be customized easily.  You can use the indexPath.section and access the row number. then you can customize that cell

Comment: Thanks Akshansh, I'm trying another solution. I'll post the reply if I solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this code set custom label frame in header view

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView()
    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15,2,self.view.frame.size.width,20))
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    lbl.text = "SOPORTE"
    lbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15)
    view.addSubview(lbl)

    return view
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to adapt but it's hard to find the right distance between the title and the first cell.

Comment: change only x value as per your requirement

Comment: Yes, but I can't know how tall is the section headerView at this moment, right?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution based on yours to make it more dynamic. I think it's very fine. I'll reply in a while. Thanks!